# Android crop изображения для всех версии

Tags: android, изображения, crop

Изначально использовал стандартные средства, но при тестировании обнаружилась проблема (описана здесь - https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). Поэтому решил использовать для Crop'a следующую библиотеку - https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop. После того как разобрался, запустил и получаю ошибку

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=6709, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {ru.fuse8.socrat/ru.fuse8.socrat.activity.MainActivity}:
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference
```

Исходный код:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        beginCrop(result.getData());
    } else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP) {
        handleCrop(resultCode, result);
    }
}

private void beginCrop(Uri source) {
    Uri destination = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), "cropped"));
    Crop.of(source, destination).asSquare().start(this);
}

private void handleCrop(int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mAvatarImageView.setImageURI(Crop.getOutput(result));
    } else if (resultCode == Crop.RESULT_ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, Crop.getError(result).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Ошибка вылетает на строчке:

```
 mAvatarImageView.setImageURI(Crop.getOutput(result));
```

P.S. до этого перепробовал 3-4 библиотеки и у всех одна и та же беда:
в Intent'e, когда заходит во второй раз в onActivityResult, как будто нет данных с отредактированным изображением.

P.S.S Объявление mAvatarImage (она находится во фрагменте, а код выше находиться в активности)

```
mAvatarImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_avatar_image_view);
    mAvatarImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 9162);
        }
    });
```

Comment: mAvatarImageView == null, покажите объявление данной переменной

Comment: проверьте как получаете mAvatarUmageView в активити.

Comment: так у вас mAvatarImageView public? во время фотографирования экран девайса крутится?

Comment: @miha_dev  mAvatarImageView обявлен public, экран не крутиться. Заблокировано.

Comment: вот в этом и проблема, не надо так делать, что бы убедиться, поставьте проверку на `null` перед вызовом метода `setImageURI`

Comment: Спасибо всем, проблема и правда оказалась в неправильном объявлений mAvatarImageView.